# How to fetch Frequently Contacts via Google Contact API in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, google-contacts-api

I am developing a project where i have to fetch all contacts with Google Contact API. I fetch some contact but i could not fetch Frequently Contacts.

so please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest not using the "Contacts" API.

[image]

But I also did find this feature request from 2018 with the latest request being May of 2021
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79731139?pli=1